# db connection in python

Tags: python, tcp, database-connection

I am writing a code in python in which I established a connection with database. I have queries in a loop. While queries being executed in the loop , If i unplug the network cable it should stop with an exception. But this not happens, When i again plug yhe network cabe after 2 minutes it starts again from where it ended. I am using linux and psycopg2. It is not showing exception

Comment: Shouting "need help urgent" is probably not the best way to get sympathy.

Answer (score 2):

Your database connection will almost certainly be based on a TCP socket. TCP sockets will hang around for a long time retrying before failing and (in python) raising an exception. Not to mention and retries/automatic reconnection attempts in the database layer.

Answer (score 2):

As Douglas's answer said, it won't raise exception due to TCP.

You may try to use socket.setdefaulttimeout() to set a shorter timeout value.

> setdefaulttimeout(...)
>
> ```
>    setdefaulttimeout(timeout)
>
>    Set the default timeout in floating seconds for new socket objects.
>    A value of None indicates that new socket objects have no timeout.
>    When the socket module is first imported, the default is None.
> ```

However, it may not work if your database connection is not build by python socket, for example, native socket.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement timeouts that work no matter how the client library is connecting to the server, it's best to attempt the DB operations in a separate thread, or, better, a separate process, which a "monitor" thread/process can kill if needed; see the multiprocessing module in Python 2.6 standard library (there's a backported version for 2.5 if you need that). A process is better because when it's killed the operating system will take care of deallocating and cleaning up resources, while killing a thread is always a pretty unsafe and messy business.

Comment: can u explain in more details

Comment: Start by reading http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html which explains how to use the multiprocessing module in the standard library (2.6 or higher Python; if you're on 2.5, install the backport from code.google.com/p/python-multiprocessing/). Not much space in a comment to give many more details, but the idea is: make two Queues quin and quout, make a Process with the Queues, and when you need a SQL query push it on quin, the Process waits on that Queue, pulls the query, does it, pushes the results on quout; the requesting process kills the other if it's taking too long.